# Want to Extract value from DWR call in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How Can i extract value from DWR call using RegEx in jmeter.

In My Script Request Body is something like :
POST data:

```
   `callCount=1` 
   `page=/abc/xyz.action`
   `httpSessionId=`
   `scriptSessionId=87F34A5261EFBF481F6D421920EF99F9406`
   `c0-scriptName=DWRPostHelper`
   `c0-methodName=savePostAsDraft`
   `c0-id=0`
   `c0-param0=string:447`
   `c0-param1=number:933`
   `c0-param2=number:0`
   `c0-param3=string:Post%20Jmeter`
   `c0-param4=string:`
   `c0-param5=string:1`
   `c0-param6=number:1427199824585`
   `batchId=4`
```

And Response data is as below :

```
   `//#DWR-INSERT`
   `//#DWR-REPLY`
   `dwr.engine._remoteHandleCallback('4','0',["447","Auto-saved at 17:55"]);`
```

Need to Extract value **447** from above Response.

is it Possible Using RegEx ? or is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'dwr\.engine\._remoteHandleCallback\('[0-9]','[0-9]',\["([0-9]+)",
```

This should do it, written from memory, you may need to tweak the syntax a bit.  Use $1$ for the template.

Comment: Outstanding, please mark this as an answer if it resolved your issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
dwr\.engine\._remoteHandleCallback\('4','0',\["(.+?)"
```

Make sure that you set `$1$` as "Template"

You can test your regular expressions using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener as follows:

[image: Regex Tester]

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more details on how to get to the bottom of failure or unexpected behavior while developing a JMeter Test